# How can axiomatic set theory handle real-life objects?

Tags: set-theory

For what I know the answer seems to be "It can't handle them" because the axiomatic set theory (at the least in its classical variation) allows only one type of objects: sets. So, for example, we can't have set of people because its elements wouldn't be just sets, they would be individual human beings (Like Donald Trump). Theoretically we could try to workaround this by creating subset "of all Donald Trumps who are current presidents of the USA". But it wouldn't be a real solution because such set must still contain Donald Trump, and as we all know Donald Trump isn't a set. Thus axiomatic set theory would be inadequate for such application.

Comment: It's not that it "can't", it's simply doesn't, because it doesn't need to. Axiomatic set theory is a mathematical theory (in the mathematical sense) about mathematical objects, and mathematical objects are not "real world objects" and "real world objects" are not mathematical objects.

Comment: There are versions of axiomatic set theory with ur-elements.

Comment: If you could please show me the object $1$ in the real world, I'd be very happy, by the way. And I don't mean an interpretation of $1$ by showing me "one cake" or "one chair" or "one sitting US president". I am not talking about real world *representations*, I am talking about $1$ itself, whatever it may be. If it is a physical object,  won't it decay eventually? Would that make the universe be without a unit? That's weird. And if something as fundamental as $1$ is not a physical object, why do you worry about sets of presidents?

Comment: Do you consider the integers to be a real life object? They are modelled in set theory by an interesting encoding using sets. Same with real numbers. You can do the same with curves and geometric objects. At that point, you can model particle systems with sets. And then it's not far to be able to model Donald Trump as a system of particles.

Comment: @asafKaragila " why do you worry about sets of presidents?" Because I'm intersted in set theory as a tool for logic. And it doesn't seem that logic would be very useful for me without real-life objects as elements of sets.

Comment: It seems to me that when you say "logic" and when I say "logic" we mean completely different things, then.

Comment: @asafKaragila Predicate logic, any bells?

Comment: Yes, which is again about mathematical objects. So I don't see Trump fitting in there very well.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I've never met an urelement. And I don't think that people *are* urelements. Urelements are inherently indistinguishable. The next step after saying that people can be modeled as urelements is arguing that this too is insufficient, because you and I are different people, and we have distinguishing features, whereas urelements are different, but have no "characterizing features".

Comment: @asafKaragila So we can't use predicate logic to deduce that Socrates is mortal? After all, you said that it's all about math. objects.  And Socrates isn't math. object.

Comment: As I said, when you say "logic" and when I say "logic" we mean different things. Just because you call them the same, and because they might dress the same, doesn't mean that they are the same. I think that I am currently applying logic, as you know it, to the whole situation.

Comment: @asafKaragila And what is the difference then between "your" and "mine" logics?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The assertion that there is a difference between the mathematical reality and physical reality is not obviously true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis

Comment: Mine is applied to mathematical objects. Yes, "all men are mortal $land$ Socrates is a man" will let you conclude that "Socrates is mortal", but only insofar as $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in A$ lets you deduce that $x\in B$. Whether or not Socrates *is* mortal, or if all men *are* mortal, I do not presume to actually know.

Comment: @Mark: Just because a smart person said it, doesn't make it any less silly.

Comment: Math connects to the real world through the process of mathematical modeling. If there is a collection of real world objects that you are considering, you can introduce a mathematical set which has one element for each such physical object. You can then reason about this mathematical set, using results from set theory if that is helpful. We then *hope* that the result of our mathematical reasoning tells us something about the real world, but it's a matter of experiment to see if the real world is accurately described by our model.

Comment: Set theory has been invented/discovered to "handle **mathematical** objects".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But much mathematics has been invented to handle real world objects. So by transitivity...

Comment: @Mark: So... computers are only useful for basic computing and breaking Nazi cryptography? They are not allowed to evolve and become their own thing for their own accord with their own internet that lets us have this conversation right now? :)

Comment: No I would think computers are widely useful for many purposes but I think I'm missing your analogy :)

Comment: Partly agreed... **Numbers** are mathematical objects: are they "real-world" objects ? What about your bank account ? Is it real-world ? Is it "made of" numbers ? Do you care if the grand total bottom right of the bank account does not fit as sum of all listed transactions ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes I care about my bank account greatly. I think the numbers inside are real in that even if I fall asleep, I believe the account still exists. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Yes; mathematical objects are [abstract objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/) with a real-life "impact". Is this enough to assert that they are "real" (and not "fictional" ) ? Maybe... Not all matth objects have the same "level of real-life impact: *sets* (the "realm" of set theory) have no impact outside math itself.

Comment: Ah yes. Any individual set does not impact my life. So sets are abstract. But by studying how sets relate to each other, I might stumble upon a theorem about the natural numbers which could certainly affect my real-life. That is to say, sets are abstract objects but set theory is a halfway real object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the particles in the universe are countable, you may assign an integer to each one. There are well known ways to model integers as sets. Now take the system of particles that currently comprise Donald Trump. This is a subset of the integers so now you have a representation of Donald Trump as a set of sets.

Edit: A major objection to my answer  is that my model is incorrect in light of modern and possibly future theories of physics. One could wonder if set theory is enough to model metaphysically correct theory of physics. I will remain agnostic to that question, but I would challenge anyone who claims to know for sure that the answer is in the negative.

Comment: They are? Do you have proof of that? Also, I am pretty sure that the set of particles consisting Trump is not constant over time.

Comment: Are you asking about countability? I believe I can argue it based on commonly accepted assumptions about physics. All you have to believe is that in an any particular cubic meter of space, there is an upper bound on the number of neutrons that can fit inside.

Comment: Well, but you didn't say "finite" you said "countable", I agree that in *the observable universe* there can only be finitely many  particles at a given moment of time (whatever that might be). But how do you know about *the universe* at all beyond what you can actually see and measure? What happens outside the observable universe? Are there countably or uncountably many others? What happens if we discover that matter is continuous, and while it clumps into quanta, it is in fact continuous. Can you disprove these statements? No, because they are metaphysical statements.

Comment: That's an interesting objection to my particular encoding of Donald Trump. But we know sets can model continuous phenomena as well. It's actually a strong claim that there can be no metaphysically accurate model of Donald Trump using sets.

Comment: Everything you can model mathematically, you can do so with sets, because sets can model everything in mathematics. Your statement is somewhat meaningless in that aspect. Even the temporal modalities can be modeled via sets, yes. But you will always have to make some metaphysical assumptions on your models which have absolutely no proof (in a mathematical sense), such as the underlying model of the universe, etc.

Comment: Yes, to show countability, you divide up the universe as a union of disjoint cubic meter regions. Using finiteness of the number of particles in each region, the "result" follows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82947/discussion-between-mark-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to leave now anyway.

Comment: Okay I wrote some comments in the chat that you can look at if you feel like it.

Comment: I doubt that "the number of particles in the universe" is a meaningful concept in the light of quantum phenomena.

Comment: @RobertLewis I edited my answer to respond to yours and Asaf's objection

Comment: Mark, just a quick remark (I will read your comments on chat once I make it to my destination), the burden of proof here is on you. You can't say "Oh, okay, so you're saying that this is not metaphysically sound because of things we do not know. So now you can't know that I'm wrong either!", sure, that is a problem on both side of the epistemological argument. But since the burden of proof here is on you, that is not a legitimate defense to this argument.

Comment: I have retreated my claim. Whether set theory can model real world objects correctly is unknown to me. If you are making the same claim, then we actually have no disagreement.

Comment: I am only claiming it's not meant for modelling the real world to begin with.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I once heard or read that some famous logician (the name Mostowski comes to mind but I don't know), on hearing someone say that everything is a set, flatly asserted "I am not a set." And someone else has said that human knowledge has not reached the point where it can answer such questions, i.e., whether Mostowski (or Trump) is a set. I don't know who that last person was either. For some reason the name Kreisel comes to mind, but that probably doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @bof Yes that captures my current opinion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes maybe it's true that set theory was invented with a certain application in mind. But it's still understandable to ask for ways in which we might abuse set theory to accomplish perverse goals.

Comment: @mark Modeling Trump as set of particles seems problematic due to Theseus's paradox. Besides, of course we can associate particles with sets of integers (i.e. enumerate them), but it raises question "Why can't we do the same thing with people?". Like Donald Trump would be associated with a set representing number 9372663 (for example).

Comment: @user161005 I have addressed this line of objections in my edit. The model is incorrect, but you may be able to modify the model to make it better. For instance, you could introduce Trump as a function whose domain is the reals (time). You could introduce quantum mechanics and other probabilistic mechanisms to model Trump as a probability cloud.

Comment: Once you include the reals, your original "oh things are finite" doesn't hold water anymore. You're undermining your own goal of basing this on "physical objects" here.